# Read Multiple QTableWidget Item's

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I am trying to read in and store all of the rows in my table into a QVariant list but every time I run the program gets to storing the data it crashes. I know it stores the data because of qDebug() but after it finishes the loop the program crashes. My code is below.

```
int RowNumber = ui->tableWidget_Invoice->rowCount();
for(int y = 0; y<=RowNumber; y++)
        {
            Qty << ui->tableWidget_Invoice->item(y, 0)->text();
            Description << ui->tableWidget_Invoice->item(y, 1)->text();
            Product_CODE << ui->tableWidget_Invoice->item(y, 2)->text();
            Unit_Price << ui->tableWidget_Invoice->item(y, 3)->text();
            Total_Price << ui->tableWidget_Invoice->item(y, 4)->text();
        }
```

Comment: `y < RowNumber` - if count is 5, last item has index 4 - how about that?

Comment: its <= so it will go through 0-5

Comment: it was originally <=

Comment: Yes, does it work with `<` ?

Comment: "but after it finishes the loop the program crashes" - ok, it has to work

Comment: What i did is i put a qDebug which tracked Y and then i read ui->tableWidget_Invoice->item(y, 0)->text(); into a Qstring which i printed to qDebug() my results were. x 0 String "22" x 1